# Phalcon PHP Paginator Bug

Tags: php, pagination, phalcon

I think there is a bug with the \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\NativeArray.

The ->next property contains the wrong value.

Here is a test case:

```
$a = array_fill(0, 25, 'banana');
echo count($a);
$paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\NativeArray(
    array(
        "data" =>$a,
        "limit"=> 25,
        "page" => 1,      
    )
);  
$test = $paginator->getPaginate();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($test);
echo '</pre>';
```

After you run this test should have the following values:

- $test->first = 1
- $test->next = 1
- $test->before = 1
- $test->current = 1
- $test->last = 2
- $test->total_pages = 2

change the array_fill value from 25 to 30 save and refresh the page.
$test->next should be 2. but it is not. it stays at 1.

is this a bug or am i doing something wrong, i am using Phalcon 0.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug,I posted the bug on  https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/445